# How to swap the XF86MonBrightnessUp and F2 key using a custom XKB layout?

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, xkb

I want to swap "two" keys, the XF86MonBrightnessUp ("brightness up") and the F2 keys, using an xkb layout. The keys are both under the same button, "F2". If the keyboard is set to multimedia it works as XF86MonBrightnessUp and if it isn't it works as F2. I keep the keyboard in multimedia mode for the most part but I hate that I lose F2, which I use often. Anyways, I have already created a custom xkb layout for this keyboard in order to swap other keys and that worked as expected but I can't seem to be able to swap these two keys using the same method. Basically I just want the "F2" key to *always* work as F2 regardless of the mode the keyboard is in. Below is my layout and the `xev` output for the key. Please note that I'm just interested in an xkb layout solution.

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "us-modded" {

 name[Group1]= "English (US, Modded)";

 include "us(alt-intl-unicode)"

 key <HOME> {   [  Prior            ]   };
 key <PGUP> {   [  Home     ]   };
 key  <END> {   [  Next         ]   };
 key <PGDN> {   [  End          ]   };

};
```

`xev` output for the key in multimedia mode:

```
KeyPress event, serial 40, synthetic NO, window 0x7600001,
    root 0x7a9, subw 0x0, time 42782231, (-443,66), root:(428,517),
    state 0x0, keycode 233 (keysym 0x1008ff02, XF86MonBrightnessUp), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

`xev` output for the key in Fn mode:

```
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x7600001,
    root 0x7a9, subw 0x0, time 42793458, (-443,66), root:(428,517),
    state 0x0, keycode 68 (keysym 0xffbf, F2), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: @Quasímodo what do you mean?

Comment: just to try out, would `xmodmap -e "keycode 233 = F2"` work?

Comment: @Quasímodo Fn mode is not set in the BIOS. Though it really doesn't matter: when the kb is in multimedia mode `xev` gets `keycode 233 (keysym 0x1008ff02, XF86MonBrightnessUp)` when I press it. I should be able to map this keycode to a different one at the xkb level although I haven't found how and the usual way doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MarceloAvila it seems to work, I get the mapped key when I press it BUT it doesn't work like F2 it's supposed to work (say, rename in my file manager). Even if it worked though, I'm looking for an xkb way to do this. xmodmap resets every time I disconnect my kb (tried several different ways to overcome that but none worked).